# Why is $V/W$ all multiples of $(0,1)^T$ given $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $W$ is all multiples of $(1,0)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

[image: Image in question]

Definitions: $v+ U \equiv \left \{v +u: u \in U   \right \}$ and $V/U \equiv \left \{v + U: v \in V  \right \}$

With these I figured that in this example $v+ W \in V/W$  would be some line parallell to the $x_1$-axis, and thus $V/W$ is all lines parallell to the $x_1$-axis.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V/W$ **is** the set of all lines, parallel to the $x$ axis.

However, as a vector space, $V/W$ is **isomorphic** to the vertical axis, as the mapping

$$(0, y)\mapsto \{(x, y)|x\in\mathbb R\}$$

is an isomorphism.

Note also that this means that $V/W$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.